# Making an object or layer transparent when another object passes over it. (Flash Actionscript 3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm very new to coding and am having trouble finishing the last little bit of a mini game type project for school.

So this is a draft of what the program looks like so far: http://aaronmillard.com/dir/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Google-Doodle_Roomba.swf

Now what I want the program to do is "vacuum" up the google when the roomba drives over it. The easiest way to achieve this (I think) is to have an exact replica of the carpet layer without the google logo beneath the carpet layer with the google logo. So I would need to code something like "when the object(roomba) passes over object(carpetwithgooglelogo) make object(carpetwithgooglelogo) have 0 opacity." I just can't figure out how to say that in code.

The code as of right now look like this:

```
// Assign 4 booleans for the 4 arrow keys
var keyUp = false;
var keyDown = false;
var keyLeft = false;
var keyRight = false;

// Add the keyboard event (KEY_DOWN) on the stage
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressKey);
function pressKey(pEvent)
{
// If an arrow key is down, switch the value to true to the assigned variable
if (pEvent.keyCode == 38)
{
    keyUp = true;
}
else if (pEvent.keyCode == 40)
{
    keyDown = true;
}
else if (pEvent.keyCode == 37)
{
    keyLeft = true;
}
else if (pEvent.keyCode == 39)
{
    keyRight = true;
}
}
// Add the keyboard event (KEY_UP) on the stage
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, releaseKey);
function releaseKey(pEvent)
{
// If the arrow key is up, switch the value to false to the assigned variable
if (pEvent.keyCode == 38)
{
    keyUp = false;
}
else if (pEvent.keyCode == 40)
{
    keyDown = false;
}
else if (pEvent.keyCode == 37)
{
    keyLeft = false;
}
else if (pEvent.keyCode == 39)
{
    keyRight = false;
}
}

// Set the velocity of the object
var speed = 4;
// And the rotation speed
var rotationSpeed = 6;

// Add an enter frame event on the moving object
myCircle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, circleEnterFrame);
function circleEnterFrame(pEvent)
{
// Set the default velocity to 0 if no key is pressed
var velocity = 0;
if (keyUp)
{
    // If the key up is pressed set the new velocity to the speed value
    velocity = speed;
}
if (keyDown)
{
    // If the key down is pressed set the new velocity to the half speed value
    velocity = -speed/2;
}
if (keyLeft)
{
    // rotate the object
    pEvent.currentTarget.rotation -=  rotationSpeed;
}
if (keyRight)
{
    // rotate the object
    pEvent.currentTarget.rotation +=  rotationSpeed;
}

// Convert the degreeAngle to the radian angle
var angleRadian = pEvent.currentTarget.rotation / 180 * Math.PI;

// Move the object with the radian angle and the object speed
pEvent.currentTarget.x +=  Math.cos(angleRadian) * velocity;
pEvent.currentTarget.y +=  Math.sin(angleRadian) * velocity;

}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: play with the blendMode property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to do something like this:

```
if( roomba.hitTestObject(google)){
    google.alpha = 0;
}
```

You'll have to check this on every frame using an `ENTER_FRAME` event.

If this is confusing tell me in the comments and I will clarify with more code.

Comment: Hi Pier, thanks for the quick response!
I might need a clarification on using the ENTER_FRAME event in conjunction with the code you already put.

The code works how I want, however it makes the entire object transparent when the "roomba" comes into contact with it. I am assuming this is what the ENTER_FRAME event is for. Yes?

Comment: No. Basically it's like a timer that gets triggered on every new frame. A more complicated explanation is that the event gets triggered whenever the object you have assigned the listener gets rendered on a new frame, hence when it "enters a frame".

If the problem is how it gets hidden, you have to change the `alpha = 0;` bit.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks for the clarification. I will need to change the alpha = 0; then.

I would want the google.alpha = 0 to only be applied to where the "roomba" object is or has been, instead of to the entire "google" object all at once. Would you know how to accomplish that?

Comment: You will need different objects for each part you want to hide. Then you put all those objects in an array, and instead of hit testing with 1 object (google in the example), you hit test each object in the array with a loop. Be aware that `hitTestObject` is the simplest way of doing it, but if you have lots of objects to test it may not  be the best option. If you want me to expand more on this please open a new question. If you find my answer to this question acceptable please accept it. It's the check button under the 0.